# How to enter a string n number of times in C using scanf()

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to enter no of test cases (t) and the for n number of times enter a string and process it. Here's the code I tried:

```
    char str[10000];
    int size,flag,i,t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        gets(str);
        flag=1;
        size=0;
        while(str[size]!='\0')  size++;
        if(size<2)  flag=0;
        for(i=0;i<size/2;i++)
            if(abs(str[i+1]-str[i])!=abs(str[size-i-1]-str[size-i-2]))  flag=0;
        if(flag)    printf("Funny\n");
        else        printf("Not Funny\n");
    }
```

Also in place of using gets, I also tried:

```
scanf("%[^\t\n]s",str);
```

But nothing seems to work

Comment: what is this code suppose to test? what the output / error you're getting?

Comment: don't use `gets`-- it is an awful habit to get into. Use `fgets` with an explicit buffer size.

Comment: from the gets manual: `Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use fgets() instead.`

Comment: `fgets` stores the newline character `\n` if it reads it, while `gets` doesn't. Remove the newline character after reading strings via `fgets`.

Comment: what exactly is the o/p and how it is different from your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got it.

```
    int t;
    char str[100];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
        scanf("%s",str);
```

This works just fine.

Comment: ...until a user enters a word with more than 99 characters, at which point you overflow the buffer.  You also don't check for errors.  Use `if (scanf("%99s", str) != 1) [ /* there was an error */ }` instead.